# Proving $S^1$ is not homeomorphic to $S^n$ for $n>1$

Tags: general-topology

I wondered how to proof this. My intuition tells me to use connectedness somehow, but im not able to see how.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit on why you think connectedness might play a role in a proof?

Comment: I think that the image of a continuous function of a connected subset is also connected. So i figured that i maybe somehow show that there exists a connected subset in $S^1$, which does not map to a connected subset in $S^n$.

Comment: If you remove two distinct points from S^1 (i.e., consider the subspace topology on their complement), the result is not connected. This is not the case for any S^n with n > 1.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to see this in $S^n$ for $n > 1$?

Comment: If you haven't seen it, there is a map called stereographic projection.  It shows that $S^n$ with a point missing is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.  So, if you take two points away from $S^n$, you get $\mathbb{R}^n$ with one point missing.

Comment: What @Rafi suggested also works for "path-connected". That might make things a bit more clear.

Comment: Oh yes you are right that makes sense thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your available tools, this can be proved in several ways :

1. $\textbf{Connectedness}$ : Let's suppose that there exists a homeomorphism $f : S^1 \rightarrow S^n$ for some fixed $n>1$, and let $p,q$ be two distinct points of $S^1$. Then $f : S^1\setminus\{p,q\} \rightarrow S^n\setminus\{f(p),f(q)\}$ is still a homeomorphism. Notice that $f(p)\neq f(q)$ because $f$ is bijective. Now, $S^1\setminus\{p,q\}$ has two connected components, and $S^n\setminus\{f(p),f(q)\}$ is connected, thus $f$ can't be a homeomorphism.
2. $\textbf{Stereographic Projection}$ Consider $N=(0,\dots,0,1)\in S^n$ the north pole and the map :
   $$
   \varphi : S^n\setminus N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \;\;\; (x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})\mapsto \left(\frac{x_1}{1-x_{n+1}},\dots,\frac{x_n}{1-x_{n+1}}\right)
   $$
   It can be shown that $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism.
   Thus $S^1 \ncong S^n$ for any $n>1$, otherwise we would have $\mathbb{R}\cong S^1\setminus N\cong S^n\setminus f(N)\cong \mathbb{R}^{n}$.
3. $\textbf{Fundamental group}$ Fundamental group of a connected space is invariant under homeomorphism. It's known that $\pi_1(S^1)\cong \mathbb{Z}$, and $\pi_1(S^n)= 0$ for any $n>0$. Thus $S^1 \ncong S^n$ for any $n>1$.
4. $\textbf{Homology}$ Homology of a space is invariant under homeomorphism. It's known that
   $$
   H_k(S^1)\cong
   \begin{cases}
           \mathbb{Z} & \text{if } k=0,1\\
           0 & \text{otherwise}
       \end{cases} \\
   H_k(S^n)\cong
   \begin{cases}
           \mathbb{Z} & \text{if } k=0,n\\
           0 & \text{otherwise}
       \end{cases}
   $$
   Thus $S^1 \ncong S^n$ for any $n>1$.